# Calling Python from C++ and accessing packages installed via Anaconda

Tags: python, c++, anaconda, conda, environment

I've developed some Python code to model a thermal device from within my base Anaconda environment. This code uses some packages, such as `numpy`, which were installed to that environment.

I would like to interface this code with a commercial thermal system modeling program on the same workstation (MS Windows 10 OS). The program/Python interface is handled through some C++ code compiled into a DLL.  A simplified snippet looks like:

```
#include <Python.h>
scriptName = "PyScript"
functionName = "InterfaceFunction"

Py_Initialize();
PyRun_SimpleString("import sys");
PyRun_SimpleString("import os");
PyRun_SimpleString("sys.path.append(os.getcwd())");

pName = PyUnicode_DecodeFSDefault(scriptName.c_str());
pModule = PyImport_Import(pName); // Here's where things go bad.
pFunc = PyObject_GetAttrString(pModule, functionName.c_str());
pValue = PyObject_CallObject(pFunc, NULL);
```

The interface works for calling a function in a simple Python script that uses only built-in Python functionality. However, the real code that I want to run requires a few `import` statements for several of the aforementioned packages installed to the base Anaconda environment. Attempting to import any of those results in a failed call when loading the script.  Specifically, the statement `pModule = PyImport_Import(pName)` results in `pModule == 'NULL'` being true.

I've already included my key Anaconda environment directories in the `PYTHONPATH` system environment variable, including:

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\DLLs
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3D\Lib\site-packages
```

I have also tried launching the calling program from a `CMD.exe` window after executing the `activate.bat base` command, but the package imports still cause failure.

Is there any way to either activate my Anaconda base environment for the calling process in the C++ code prior to the `PyImport_Import()` call to get modules to properly import? Or am I just stuck needing to drop Anaconda's environments and freshly install python and all the needed modules without using environments?

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to run a python script within conda using the base environment, try something this, replacing the -V with your python script:

```
conda run -n base python -V
```

Python 3.7.6

from within C++, if you are able to run a python script, you can try this:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run('c:\\Users\\iowahawk89\\miniconda3\\condabin\\conda.bat activate base && "c:\\Users\\iowahawk89\\miniconda3\\Scripts\\conda.exe" "list" && conda deactivate', shell=True)

subprocess.run('c:\\Users\\iowahawk89\\miniconda3\\Scripts\\conda.exe run -n base python hello.py', shell=True)
```

or if you want to run python in the interpreter directly, you can try this:

```
subprocess.run('c:\\Users\\iowahawk89\\miniconda3\\Scripts\\conda.exe run -n base python -V', shell=True)
```

other ideas:

```
subprocess.run('c:\\Users\\iowahawk89\\miniconda3\\Scripts\\conda.exe run -n base python -V', shell=True)

subprocess.run('c:\\Users\\iowahawk89\\miniconda3\\Scripts\\conda.exe run -n base python hello.py', shell=True)
```

save the output for use later

```
output = subprocess.check_output(['c:\\Users\\iowahawk89\\miniconda3\\Scripts\\conda.exe', 'list', '-n', 'base'])
print('Have %d bytes in output' % len(output))
print(output)

output = subprocess.check_output(['c:\\Users\\iowahawk89\\miniconda3\\condabin\\conda.bat', 'activate', 'base'], shell=True)
```

In all cases, i am able to see the correct python version from my conda environment.

Comment: Thanks Donald, but unfortunately I'm not calling the script from a command line but rather from within a compiled C++ function using the Python API found in the "Python.h" header. I did try to run the environment configuration command via `std::system("activate.bat base");` within the source code prior to the Python calls, but that command didn't seem to impact the calling program.

Comment: I added a few options above, hopefully one of them will solve your particular problem.

Comment: @DonaldS While the above ideas to provide a way forward in using Anaconda from C++ with Python, it is less than ideal. Typically, when you use Python from C++, you want to run specific functions, not an entire script. For example: PyObject* myModule = PyImport_Import(pyModuleName); PyObject* myFunction = PyObject_GetAttrString(myModule, functionName.c_str()); PyObject* myResult = PyObject_CallObject(myFunction, args);